# Create all possible month-country pairs in SQLite

Tags: sqlite, grouping

I have one table that contains many fields. Three of them are "month", "event" and "country".

For each month, I want to see the total number of events for each country, even if there were none. Then I want the sum to be shown as zero.

The output should be something like this

| month | country | number_of_events |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | A | 0 |
| 12 | B | 10 |
| 12 | C | 1 |
| 11 | A | 100 |
| 11 | B | 2 |
| 10 | A | 8 |

This is my current SQLite-Code, but using it yields in an output that does exclude the countries that had zero events in that month ...

```
SELECT month, country, SUM(events) AS number_of_events
FROM table
WHERE country IN ('A','B','C')
GROUP BY month DESC
```

Can you help me? Which SQLite-Command would be suitable for my task?

Thank you!

Comment: Use the `total()` SQL function instead. See the [docs](https://sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html#sumunc). `sum()` returns `NULL` for all-NULL inputs.

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate all possible pairs of month/country and then LEFT JOIN them with the table.
You can do this with a couple of Common Table Expressions.

As Mark Benningfield suggested, use TOTAL() instead of SUM() to get a 0 instead of NULL where you don't have any data point.

```
WITH months(m) AS (VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12)),
     countries(c) AS (VALUES ('A'),('B'),('C'))
SELECT months.m, countries.c, TOTAL(table.events)
FROM months JOIN countries LEFT JOIN table ON (table.month=months.m AND table.country=countries.c)
GROUP BY months.m, countries.c
ORDER BY months.m DESC, countries.c;
```

If you don't know what countries are present in the table, you can generate the list from the table itself (the same could be done for months):

```
WITH months(m) AS (VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12)),
     countries(c) AS (SELECT DISTINCT country c FROM table)
SELECT months.m, countries.c, TOTAL(table.events)
FROM months JOIN countries LEFT JOIN table ON (table.month=months.m AND table.country=countries.c)
GROUP BY months.m, countries.c
ORDER BY months.m DESC, countries.c;
```